# Which design pattern should I use to output different content using one template?

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I need to extend a piece of code that writes a paragraph using constant strings defined in an interface:

```
public class paragraphGenerator implements EnglishParaGraph(){
    public StringBuffer outputParagraph = new StringBuffer();

    public void generate(){
        writeParagraph(PARA1);
        //some long and complicated logic here
        writeParagraph(PARA2);
        //some long and complicated logic here
        writeParagraph(PARA3);
    }

    public void writeParagraph(String content){
        //manipulates the paragraph and puts it in stringbuffer
    }
}

public interface EnglishParaGraph{
    public static final String PARA1 = "Hello";
    public static final String PARA2 = "Thank you";
    public static final String PARA3 = "Goodbye";
}
```

Running `generate()` should write something like "Hello Thank you Goodbye". 
Now I want to generate a French equivalent so the output looks something like "Bonjour Merci Salut".

According to [Template Method Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/template-method-pattern.html) can overwrite `generate()` in a subclass and change each `writeParagraph`'s input argument, but that will repeat most of the code which is not desirable.

What's the most suitable design pattern to use here? I was told to use as little replicating code as possible.

Answer (score 0):

The design of the interface and extending class is simply wrong. To be clear, interfaces are specifically used to avoid defining implementation details. The code you posted does the exact opposite of that and defines implementation details using an interface.

At worst, you want to make the interface define something like this:

```
public interface ParagraphSource{
    public String getParagraph1Text();
    public String getParagraph2Text();
    public String getParagraph3Text();
}

public class EnglishSource extends ParagraphSource {

    public String getParagraph1Text() {
        return "Hello";
    }
    public String getParagraph2Text() {
        return "Thank you"; 
    }
    public String getParagraph3Text() {
        return "Goodbye";
    }
}

public class FrenchSource extends ParagraphSource {

    public String getParagraph1Text() {
        return "Bonjour";
    }
    public String getParagraph2Text() {
        return "Merci"; 
    }
    public String getParagraph3Text() {
        return "Au revoir";
    }
}
```

Then your paragraph generator can use different sources:

```
public class ParagraphGenerator {
    public StringBuffer outputParagraph = new StringBuffer();

    public void generate(ParagraphSource source){

        writeParagraph(source.getParagraph1Text());
        //some long and complicated logic here
        writeParagraph(source.getParagraph2Text());
        //some long and complicated logic here
        writeParagraph(source.getParagraph3Text());
    }
}
```

Comment: That interface is meant to be a container for constant values. I think your design is cleaner but requires too much change to the code base

Comment: >That interface is meant to be a container for constant values.         well, this is just bad code. you can say you don't want to fix it, but the solution to your question requires fixing it...

Comment: What is a more acceptable way of storing a large list of constants?